# Installing Zend Optimizer with MAMP Pro 3

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

So the documentation for MAMP 
http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/

says,

> Can I activate and deactivate eAccelerator and Zend Optimizer?
>
> Yes. Check Preferences... > PHP in the MAMP Preferences Panel.

but there is no such setting in the MAMP Preferences panel or in the MAMP Main Window.

Can this no longer be done? I am using Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Zend Optimizer is **no longer supported** out of the box.
Your options are:

MAMP->PHP->**Caching**

[image]

Or you can install it manually.

Comment: That doesn't give you access to the Zend Optimizer (at least as far as I can see on mine or yours).

Comment: sorry I only read "eAccelerator". I guess Zend Optimizer is no longer supported.